# How to fix a Brackets Error

Tags: html

I am taking a udemy course about html. I installed a program called Brackets, but I ran into a snag. Here is a screen shot of the program:
[image: Brackets]

If you right click on the left side of the screen in the gray area, a menu will pop up. The instructor wants me to make a new folder, we are making external links. However, I get this error-"An error occurred after trying to create the directory css.(Error Unknown) At first I thought it might be the actual name of the directory but it isn't, I tested it with my own name. Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're not creating the directory in the default Getting Started directory.

Comment: @LeoLam- you were right, if you make it an answer I will vote for it.

Comment: Just FYI, you can also answer your own question by posting a community wiki answer and accepting it. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your current opened project/directory in Brackets is the default *Getting Started* project. This means that whenever you create a new file or directory in the sidebar, Brackets is trying to create a file or directory in that demo project, which likely fails because it does not have permission to write there.

To fix this, simply open a directory where you have permission to write to.